# How to exclude the base.apk from Android Auto Backup?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-backup-service

I'd like to configure the Android Auto Backup feature to exclude the base.apk file. I already tried to explicitly call the apk file on my custom backup file. Like this:

```
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/custom_backup_rules"

custom_backup_rules.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<full-backup-content>
    <exclude domain="file" path="base.apk"/>
</full-backup-content>
```

But I did not have any success. Does someone know if it is possible to do such a thing?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to back up and exclude the apk?

There is open source code which might help you.

https://github.com/zjkhiyori/ApkExtractorMD

It could exclude the apk file of app directly.
Remember to get the storage permission if you test this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
Actually, what I want is to avoid someone or some application could backup my app and extract this base.apk file.
My first idea was to remove this file from backup use the XML configuration above.